# Saving new indicies, triangles and normals after WPF 3D transform

Tags: c#, wpf, 3d, transform, savechanges

I have a 3D model which is lying flat currently, I wish for it to be rotated 90 degrees around the X axis. I have no problem doing this with the transforms. But to my knowledge all the transforms are a bunch of matrices multiplied. I would like to have the transform really alter all the coordinates of the indicies of the model. Is there a way to "save changes" after I apply a transform?
I wish to be able to use the XamlWriter class to save the new Geometry, in a xaml file, not in a way that it has the old geometry and then applied transform, I wish to save the new coordinaes.

Answer (score 1):

Erm, yes you apply the transform to each coordinate.  The result is a new coordinate, which you can save however you like.

I'm not familiar with 3D in WPF but I'm sure this is what it's already doing.